# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView isAnimating]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios

Newbie to xcode and objective-c. so forgive my rookie mistakes but I've had this error "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView isAnimating]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" for over a day now and have done much searching with no prevail. There's no errors when I clean/build the app but when I click on a button to load the "UIIMagePickerController" the app terminates and throws the error. please help. thx

```
- (void)showImagePickerForSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    if (self.imageView.isAnimating)
    {
        [self.imageView stopAnimating];
    }

    if (self.capturedImages.count > 0)
    {
        [self.capturedImages removeAllObjects];
    }

    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverlayView" owner:self options:nil];
        self.overlayView.frame = imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;
        imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;
        self.overlayView = nil;
    }

    self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
   [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: Show your code. Where are you calling `isAnimating`? How are you retaining the image picker?

Comment: Did you check `imageView` is really an image view. When do you start it animating?

Answer (score 1):

Your code `self.imageView.isAnimating` is being turned into [something similar to] this by the compiler:

```
[[self imageView] isAnimating]
```

According to the error message, `[self imageView]` is returning a `UIView` object. There is no method `isAnimating` on the `UIView` class, so you get an exception.

Find out where `[self imageView]` is being set, perhaps it's doing something wrong there? Also, do you have ARC turned on? It could be a memory management bug.

Comment: Yep! that was it! Sooo simple! Both Wain and Abhi's answers contributed to the solution. I must have accidentally deleted the UIImageView from the controller. I just started programming a week ago and really appreciate your help guys! is there any way I can give you credit for helping me on here? I can't up vote anything yet cause I'm too new. But Thank you guys so much, programmers are the most friendly people i've ever encountered!

Comment: @JaredGross, you can mark the answer as correct. P.s. Welcome to the world of code :-)

Comment: @JaredGross aside from accepting someone's answer, also make sure you upvote any answer or comment that was helpful. You also get rewarded for accepting answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your line:

```
if (self.imageView.isAnimating)
```

to

```
if ([self.imageView isAnimating])
```

And make sure `self.imageView` is indeed and `UIImageView`

Comment: Those two lines, while syntactically different, are actually equivalent. The part about making sure self.imageView is a UIImageView is correct, though.

Answer (score 0):

That error message means that you're trying to send a message (*roughly* equivalent to calling a function in Java, C++, or most other languages) to an object that doesn't implement it. This is something that makes Objective C different than many other popular languages. I recommend giving [this article](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/sthompson/understanding-objective-c-messaging) a read, specifically the part that says

> the system determines, at run-time, while a program is executing, whether or not a given object responds to a particular message and if so, which method is executed.

Also, as others have pointed out, the error message says that your `imageView` object is a `UIView` and not a `UIImageView`. Figuring out why this is should solve your immediate problem.

Comment: Yes, the error was in imageView now actually being a UIImageView. I must have accidentally deleted the original UIImageView or linked imageView up to the viewController instead. Either way, I'm moving on!